# Error while creating function : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I new to sql server, I try to create a function like below mentioned

```
CREATE FUNCTION Proc_Emp_Active_GRP (@Str_Date DATETIME) RETURNS @Result TABLE (Column_Values VARCHAR(8000)) AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @Result(Column_Values)
  WITH W_LOCATION_TRANS AS (Select EMPID, LOCATION_CODE, LOCATION_FROM_DATE FROM_DATE, LOCATION_TO_DATE TO_DATE, MAX(LOCATION_FROM_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY (EMPID)) MAX_FROM_DATE,COMP_CODE
                          FROM
    HR_Location_Transfer
  WHERE
    Location_From_Date <= ISNULL(@Str_Date,GETDATE())),

 W_LOCATION_FINAL AS( Select
   A.EMPID, A.FROM_DATE FROM_DATE,C.LOC_CODE, A.LOCATION_CODE ,C.LOC_NAME,A.COMP_CODE
From
   W_LOCATION_TRANS A, HR_LOC_MASTER C
Where
   A.From_Date= A.Max_From_Date And  A.LOCATION_CODE = C.LOC_CODE),

   W_EMP_STATUS AS(SELECT
    A.EMPID,A.STATUS_CODE,B.STATUS_NAME,B.STATUS_GROUP,A.STATUS_DATE
  FROM
    HR_STATUS_ENTRY A ,HR_STATUS B
  WHERE
    A.STATUS_CODE  =B.STATUS_CODE AND
    B.STATUS_GROUP ='STAT02' AND
    A.STATUS_DATE <= ISNULL(@Str_Date,GETDATE())
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    A.EMPID,'STAT99','ON LEAVE','STAT99',A.FROM_DATE
  FROM
    HR_ANNUALLEAVE A LEFT OUTER JOIN HR_ANNUAL_LEAVE_REJOIN B ON A.DOC_CODE = b.annualleave_doc_code
  WHERE
    ISNULL(B.REJOIN_DATE,ISNULL(@Str_Date,GETDATE())+1)> ISNULL(@Str_Date,GETDATE()) AND
    A.FROM_DATE <=ISNULL(@Str_Date,GETDATE())
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    A.EMPID,'STAT98', 'NOT JOINED', 'STAT98', GETDATE()
  FROM
    HR_EMPLOYEE A
  WHERE
    ISNULL(A.JOINDATE,GETDATE()+1) > ISNULL(@Str_Date,GETDATE())),

    W_EMP_STATUS_FIRST AS( SELECT A.EMPID, A.STATUS_CODE, A.STATUS_NAME, A.STATUS_GROUP, STATUS_DATE, MAX(STATUS_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY A.EMPID) MAX_STATUS_DATE, MAX(STATUS_GROUP)
    OVER (PARTITION BY A.EMPID) MAX_STATUS_GROUP
  FROM W_EMP_STATUS A),
   W_App_Check AS (SELECT DOC_CODE, DOC_STATUS FROM VW_APP_CHECK),
   W_EMP_STATUS_FINAL AS(
     SELECT A.EMPID,A.STATUS_CODE,A.STATUS_NAME,A.STATUS_GROUP,STATUS_DATE
  FROM W_EMP_STATUS_FIRST A
  WHERE A.STATUS_DATE=A.MAX_STATUS_DATE AND A.STATUS_GROUP=A.MAX_STATUS_GROUP)
  SELECT A.EMPID, A.EMPID EMPCODE, A.FIRSTNAME, A.LASTNAME, A.FIRSTNAME+' '+A.LASTNAME EMPNAME, A.JOINDATE,
    A.DESIGNATION_CODE, A.SUBDEPT_CODE, A.JOB_CODE, A.TRADE_CODE, A.GRADE_CODE, A.SPONSOR_CODE, A.EMPTYPE_CODE,
    C.PAYTYPE_CODE, C.PAYMODE_CODE, C.BANK_CODE, C.BANK_ACCTNO, C.ATTENDANCE_TYPE, C.NORMAL_OT_RATE, C.HOLIDAY_OT_RATE,
    B.LOC_CODE, A.ACCT_CODE, A.COMP_CODE, X.STATUS_GROUP STATUS_GROUP, ISNULL(D.DOC_STATUS,'APPROVED'), C.VACATION_SALARY, C.IBAN
  FROM HR_EMPLOYEE A RIGHT OUTER JOIN W_LOCATION_FINAL B ON A.EMPID = B.EMPID RIGHT OUTER JOIN W_EMP_STATUS X ON A.EMPID = X.EMPID AND X.STATUS_GROUP = 'STAT02'
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN HR_EMP_PAYMENT_INFO C ON A.EMPID = C.EMPID RIGHT OUTER JOIN W_App_Check D ON A.EMPID = D.DOC_CODE WHERE X.EMPID IS NULL;
  RETURN
END
GO
```

But its showing error : `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'`.

Comment: Welcome to the light side of SQL. :) OP should add tag `ORACLE` if you are skilled SQL, just unfamiliar with `MSSQL`. Also, Microsoft's documentation blows Oracle out of the water. Please refer to [MSDN - WITH CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) syntax questions and read awesome SQL Server Masters like [Dave Pinal](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/05/19/sql-server-cte-can-be-updated/)   .If you end up hating `Oracle`, Mission Accomplished. ;)

Answer (score 0):

So many mistakes are there not sure which one to point out. I guess you need something like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION Proc_emp_active_grp (@Str_Date DATETIME)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN
      WITH W_LOCATION_TRANS
           AS (SELECT EMPID,
                      LOCATION_CODE,
                      LOCATION_FROM_DATE        FROM_DATE,
                      LOCATION_TO_DATE          TO_DATE,
                      Max(LOCATION_FROM_DATE)
                        OVER (
                          PARTITION BY (EMPID)) MAX_FROM_DATE,
                      COMP_CODE
               FROM   HR_Location_Transfer
               WHERE  Location_From_Date = Isnull(@Str_Date, Getdate())
                      AND A.FROM_DATE = Isnull(@Str_Date, Getdate())),
           W_EMP_STATUS_FIRST
           AS (SELECT A.EMPID,
                      A.STATUS_CODE,
                      A.STATUS_NAME,
                      A.STATUS_GROUP,
                      STATUS_DATE,
                      Max(STATUS_DATE)
                        OVER (
                          PARTITION BY A.EMPID) MAX_STATUS_DATE,
                      Max(STATUS_GROUP)
                        OVER (
                          PARTITION BY A.EMPID) MAX_STATUS_GROUP
               FROM   W_EMP_STATUS A),
           W_App_Check
           AS (SELECT DOC_CODE,
                      DOC_STATUS
               FROM   VW_APP_CHECK),
           W_EMP_STATUS_FINAL
           AS (SELECT A.EMPID,
                      A.STATUS_CODE,
                      A.STATUS_NAME,
                      A.STATUS_GROUP,
                      STATUS_DATE
               FROM   W_EMP_STATUS_FIRST A
               WHERE  A.STATUS_DATE = A.MAX_STATUS_DATE
                      AND A.STATUS_GROUP = A.MAX_STATUS_GROUP)
      SELECT A.EMPID,
             A.EMPID                        EMPCODE,
             A.FIRSTNAME,
             A.LASTNAME,
             A.FIRSTNAME + ' ' + A.LASTNAME EMPNAME,
             A.JOINDATE,
             A.DESIGNATION_CODE,
             A.SUBDEPT_CODE,
             A.JOB_CODE,
             A.TRADE_CODE,
             A.GRADE_CODE,
             A.SPONSOR_CODE,
             A.EMPTYPE_CODE,
             C.PAYTYPE_CODE,
             C.PAYMODE_CODE,
             C.BANK_CODE,
             C.BANK_ACCTNO,
             C.ATTENDANCE_TYPE,
             C.NORMAL_OT_RATE,
             C.HOLIDAY_OT_RATE,
             B.LOC_CODE,
             A.ACCT_CODE,
             A.COMP_CODE,
             X.STATUS_GROUP                 STATUS_GROUP,
             Isnull(D.DOC_STATUS, 'APPROVED') as DOC_STATUS,
             C.VACATION_SALARY,
             C.IBAN
      FROM   HR_EMPLOYEE A
             RIGHT OUTER JOIN W_LOCATION_FINAL B
                           ON A.EMPID = B.EMPID
             RIGHT OUTER JOIN W_EMP_STATUS X
                           ON A.EMPID = X.EMPID
                              AND X.STATUS_GROUP = 'STAT02'
             RIGHT OUTER JOIN HR_EMP_PAYMENT_INFO C
                           ON A.EMPID = C.EMPID
             RIGHT OUTER JOIN W_App_Check D
                           ON A.EMPID = D.DOC_CODE
      WHERE  X.EMPID IS NULL
```

Comment: It was a oracle based function and i am trying to change to sql server. Query is working fine in oracle. here i am changing only parameter and getdate(). my doubt is how get values from this to a table()

Comment: Did you create the above function. After creating just select the function `select * from Proc_emp_active_grp(getdate())`. The result can be inserted into any table

Comment: CREATE FUNCTION Proc_Emp_Active_GRP (@Str_Date DATETIME) RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN
  WITH W_LOCATION_TRANS AS (Select EMPID, LOCATION_CODE, LOCATION_FROM_DATE FROM_DATE, LOCATION_TO_DATE TO_DATE, MAX(LOCATION_FROM_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY (EMPID)) MAX_FROM_DATE,COMP_CODE
                          FROM
    HR_Location_Transfer
  WHERE
    Location_From_Date <= ISNULL(@Str_Date,GETDATE())), etc
 
 but its giveing error  CREATE FUNCTION failed because a column name is not specified for column 25.

Comment: Now i have some thing issue with

Comment: Now i have issue with Select EMPID, LOCATION_CODE, LOCATION_FROM_DATE FROM_DATE, LOCATION_TO_DATE TO_DATE, MAX(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),LOCATION_FROM_DATE,110)) OVER (PARTITION BY (EMPID)) MAX_FROM_DATE,COMP_CODE
                          FROM
    HR_Location_Transfer
  WHERE
    Location_From_Date<= ISNULL('01-JUN-2016',GETDATE()) is ther any mistake in MAX(LOCATION_FROM_DATE) do need any kind on=f conversion for this

Comment: I thought the error message was saying the OP isn't terminating their SQL statements with a semicolon, which is about the only thing you *didn't* correct!

Comment: @Jerin are you geeting any error if yes then post the error message

Comment: @Prdp, SQL Server Database Error: Operand type clash: int is incompatible with datetime2